# Is using AsyncTask on every activity a good practise?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I would like to know if it is a good practice to use `AsyncTask` on every activity in my app? I need to improve the speed at which my activities load and `AsyncTask` should do the trick. Are there risks of doing it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to identify what is taking time use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to profile the activity. It is generally a bad idea to try to optimize before identifying the culprit causing lag.

With that said you should enable [Strict Mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) to catch performance bugs early.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

As per developer.google says:

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

You can perform your all process without `asynctask` below API level 10. 
But You should use it whenever there is probability that

your process will take long time to execute and it is running on your Main UI.
This type of process can be like you are making connection to the server, Using internet, Downloading some image, Running a url. In all above cases you have to use async task so that these processes will not run on MainUI and didnt block your main .

This link will help you in some way. [:)](http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/android-async-task/)

Comment: +1 for the link, I should probably find the cause of the delay first. At the moment I think the image quality in my `gridview` may be slowing the app down. I can still try to fix it by decreasing the image quality.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you really want. You have to remember that you cannot have everything. If you are trying to improve speed, you will have to loose space. AsyncTasks will occupate more space.

Everytime you will have this relation between memory x proccessing

Answer (score 0):

By calling AsyncTask, you just end up creating another thread which is maintained by system. So, depends on what you have to load in activity. If your loading is heavy operation, then you should call asysnctask rather than blocking your UI thread. You app will just end up consuming little more memory during runtime..

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: if it improves speed as you said it does. Than it is not bad practise.